# Supercuspidals of GL(n) and the induced representation $Ind_{T}^{G}1_{T}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be the group $GL(n,F)$, where $F$ is a non-archimedean local field. Is it true that for any smooth irreducible supercuspidal representation (with trivial central character) $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ we have
$$\dim_{\mathbb{C}}Hom_{T}(\pi,1_T)=1,$$
where $T$ is the diagonal torus of $G$ ? By Frobenuis reciprocity the result is equivalent to say that
$$\dim_{\mathbb{C}}Hom_{G}(\pi,Ind_{T}^{G}1_{T})=1$$
Is there any reference on the subject ?

Comment: Certainly not if the central character of $\pi$ is nontrivial - it will be zero instead.

Comment: In fact, I want the result in exactly this case, that is when $\pi$ have trivial central character.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01445212